# Convert all 0 value image pixels to 255 in tensorflow

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, deep-learning, opencv3.0

I am new to tensorflow,

I need to convert all 0 value pixels to 255 on a 3d image tensor

I can do it in cv like this

`img[np.where((img == [0, 0, 0]).all(axis=2))] = [255, 255, 255]`

But, I need help to find out how to do this in tensorflow. As i need to do this in a tensorflow graph

Comment: check out `tf.where`, `tf.reduce_all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
img = tf.cast(tf.equal(img, tf.zeros_like(img)), tf.int32)*255 + img
```